# RANK(), DENSE_RANK(), and COUNT() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, count, nested, rank

I have a table of students who use programs/PGMs at the College.  I want to know, in a given month, for the top 100 PGMs:

1. how many times the program/PGM was run (in a month),
2. the ranking of the PGM,
3. how many total ... unique SIDs ... Student ID ran the PGM, and
4. the ranking of the count of unique students

I was given this MS SQL 2010 code below ... to find the top 100 PGMs/programs.  I've really cleaned up my hacking around of nested SELECTs, COUNT, COUNT DISTINCT, RANK, etc ... Trust me, I've tried, copying SQL from other problems and answers.  I was hoping not to have tp make a temporary table.  Everything I tried was 'no joy' :(
So i thought I would email the StackOverflow community.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
SELECT TOP 100
    T.PGM AS 'Program'
    ,COUNT (*) AS 'Program Count'

FROM StudentPrograms T

WHERE 
    T.PGM <>'unknown'
    AND T.CreateDate > '10/01/2015'
    AND T.CreateDate < '10/31/2015'

 GROUP BY       
   T.PGM

ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
    ;
```

I should end up with 5 columns in a table

1. Program
2. Program Count
3. Program Rank (will be 1 through 100 ... boring I know ... but that's OK for now)
4. Student Count
5. Student Rank (won't be straight 1 to 100 but scattered around a bit)

Comment: what is `MS SQL 2010`?

Comment: You need to provide us more information on the tables and columns you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ranking, perhaps [`rank()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will do want you want:

```
SELECT TOP 100
       T.PGM AS Program, COUNT(*) AS ProgramCount,
       RANK() OVER (Order BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ranking
FROM StudentPrograms T
WHERE T.PGM <>'unknown' AND
      T.CreateDate > '2015-10-01' AND
      T.CreateDate < '2015-10-31'  -- We don't like Halloween
GROUP BY  T.PGM
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: FYI @GPS Ger, this query excludes the 31st of October (as does your original), hence the Halloween comment.  Also I submitted an edit, but if you want the Student Count/Rank as well, simply copy the `COUNT` and `RANK` lines and replace the `*` with `DISTINCT SID`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this ... but seriously ... the server is down.

Comment: Also, thanks for the Halloween catch as well.  Of note, I'm a huge String Cheese Incident fan -- and their Hulaween is just as important to me as well.

Comment: And are you at SAS --> Gordon S. Linoff